# how to remove a content of (::before) or just hide the before content

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my case i want to delete the content of (::before) or hide it in jquery/javacript

Can anyone help please ?

I have trying this but it's not working

```
$(".element").attr('data-before','');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly target `::before` with jQuery or inline styling, only with CSS.

You could add a class to the element with a CSS rule that hides its `::before` content when it has that class:

```css
.element.hide-before::before {
    display: none;
}
```

```js
$(".element").addClass("hide-before");
```

Live Example:

```js
setInterval(() => {
    $(".element").toggleClass("hide-before");
}, 1000);
```

```css
.element::before {
    content: "::before content";
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
.element.hide-before::before {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"> inline content</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you wanted to be able to control the *content* via JavaScript code, you could make the content come from an attribute (Like your `data-before`):

```css
.element::before {
    content: attr(data-before);
}
```

Then you could "remove" it by making it blank:

```js
$(".element").attr("data-before", "");
```

but you could also change it to something else by providing a non-empty string.

Live Example:

```js
let counter = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    ++counter;
    $(".element").attr("data-before", counter === 4 ? "" : `before ${counter}`);
    if (counter === 4) {
        counter = -1;
    }
}, 1000);
```

```css
.element::before {
    content: attr(data-before);
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="element" data-before="before 0"> inline</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```